# TraCI Documentation Query

Tags: python, sumo

I'm not able to access data of TraCI package which should apparently have instances of all Domain classes.I tried creating those classes manually but it caused some connection problems.

I was running the simulation when an error occurred

**'NoneType' object has no attribute '_sendReadOneStringCmd'
for the code**
 `result = self._connection._sendReadOneStringCmd`

On investigating further i found that self._connection is being set to None though initials it was set to a Connection type object.

I think this is because I initialized TrafficLaneDomain() LaneAreaDomain() and similar other classes in my code.
The Documentation attached shows the instances present ,but i'm unable to acces it.
Is this the error or anything else might be wrong?

[TraCI DOC Home](http://sumo.dlr.de/pydoc/traci.html)

Comment: Please add some code. What exactly did you try and which errors occurred?

Comment: edited the question accordingly

Comment: There is no need to instantiate the domain classes. Why did you do so?